# How to develop JavaFX applications with Openjdk?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, java

On Netbeans every time I choose a new JavaFx Application project it will ask me to "add a platform" unless I add the Oracle Java JDK I will be stuck there. Is there a way to use Openjdk to get around the problem?

Comment: What kind of research do you made so far and how about using [openjfx](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/getting-started.html)? Or why did you left it out of your scope?

Comment: Actually, Stack Overflow is the proper place to ask questions regarding the use of IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a self-contained application/installer with the Oracle JDK and you are done. What's the problem?

(By someone who doesn't care about the deep religious aspects of free software :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hummm... Either I'm missing something or I don't understand. :(  You will need the JDK to program Java applications.As far as building Java GUI, Have you given JavaFX scene builder a shot? check it out here: [Java FX scenbuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html). If I'm missing something please let me know. Seems like I am...

Comment: Ok so I developed a JavaFX application with Scenbuilder it's done. The thing is that I used the normal Oracle JDK. For Linux there is also Openjdk. My problem is that the jar file will only run under a Oracle JRE and not under a Openjdk jre.

Comment: And this is when you try to compile in Netbeans or after you've got it compiled and built with a complete jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this answer to a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529820/4773709

Basicly, it says that you can build an openJDK version which includes JavaFX (OpenJFX) following the instructions given [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) .

But there are no linux distribution that offer a JavaFX package, meaning, if you develop an application using JavaFX, the OpenJDK users won't be able to use it unless they've also built their OpenJDK themselves.