# Is JavaFX supported in Openjdk?

Tags: javafx-8, java

Does OpenJDK 8 includes JavaFX support like Oracle Java does? I know there  is package (at least for Ubuntu) called OpenJFX, but I'm not sure why that's not included in OpenJDK 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, you can](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/). Java is platform-agnostic. By the way you can also use Oracle JDK on Linux.

Comment: And how do I create a Openjfx application? Its not available on Netbeans.

Comment: Add the JAR to your classpath. What do you mean *"not available on Netbeans"*?

Comment: I mean that when I choose a new project there is not openjfx option only JavaFX, Java, sorry if I sound a little newbie.

Comment: Probably Netbeans doesn't have native/plugin support for JavaFX yet (in fact Eclipse and IDEA also don't IIRC). This is probably due to the fact that JavaFX is still "green" and has quite a few bugs (at least it did a couple of months ago when we decided to use it, then went back to Swing). Anyway, it doesn't matter because you can still link the API through the classpath.

Comment: No it does. Look In netebans using Oracle JDK and Scenebuilder I build a app. The problem s that I want to make a .deb and I can't require Oracel JRE only Openjdk-jre. But openjdk-jre will not run fx apps. But I think I will just copy a jar file in the Openjdk folder as you recomanded

Answer (score 2):

The word "supported" means different things to different people.

Here is the official [JavaFX Supported Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) page which describes the various platforms on which JavaFX2 is "certified".  The page makes no mention of OpenJDK, so Oracle may take the position that JavaFX is "not certified" for OpenJDK.

On the other hand JavaFX is part of the codebase managed by the OpenJDK project.

In practice, I think that this means that JavaFX works on OpenJDK ... except for a couple cases where JavaFX requires Java functionality that is not in OpenJDK.  See this Q&A for a more detailed explanation.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529820/139985

---

> I was wondering if I can develop JavaFX applications, with Netbeans, on OpenJDK 8?

Different question.  In this case, the answer is uncategorical.  Yes you can.  The NetBeans 8 [release notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/relnotes.html) say that JavaFX is supported, and do not specify that Oracle Java is required, or even preferred over OpenJDK Java.

Answer (score 1):

To make this more clear, OpenJDK does not include JavaFX as of July 2016.  Their web page has instructions, which I have not tried, for building OpenJDK with JFX from source, which seems a little self-abusive.  I have very recently started using Oracle's JDK instead when I need JavaFX in Fedora.  I remember reading a warning somewhere on the Fedora Project wiki that the parallel installs could cause problems, but I am betting that a version that is installed carefully using good path hygiene will be OK.  No problems yet.