# Running .jar file throws exception when run with openjdk 13.0.2

Tags: java

I want to run some .jar files with openJDK 13.0.2.
To run them, i use `java -jar nameGoesHere.jar` via cmd (Windows 10)

For one .jar i get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

An other one shows me:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ClassNameGoesHere
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

When Using java 1.8.0_241 the .jar files run as expected.

I can not figure out what causes these problems. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add the missing depencies which were bundled in Java 8 when you execute your jar with Java 13.

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaFX comes with JDK 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974003/javafx-comes-with-jdk-8) and [Is JavaFX supported in Openjdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142746/is-javafx-supported-in-openjdk) you can see that JavaFX is bundled with JDK 8, but to get it working with OpenJDK you need to follow some instructions.