# How to require Oracle Java (JRE) when building a .deb (debian package)?

Tags: java, javafx-8, deb

I wrote a small BTRFS GUI in Oracle Java that uses JavaFX. So in orded for the program to work Oracle Java (JRE) must be installed (not Openjdk-jre!). How can I require that when building the .deb package under the control file?

Comment: Fix your program so it works in OpenJDK?

Comment: Here's the thing If I use the Openjdk JDK it won't recognize javafx calsess. I can't even create a JavaFX Apllication in Netbeans if I set the JDK to Openjdk. If you find a way to use Openjdk for JavaFX development, tell me.

Comment: Maybe you will have more luck bundling the Java runtime with your application, despite the possible bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian has an [OpenJFX package for Java 8](https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openjfx.html), which you can install in addition to the standard OpenJDK package.

Debian's OpenJFX package brings JavaFX capabilities to Debian based systems (and can be used as an alternative to installing Oracle JDK 8+ which also includes JavaFX capabilities implicitly).

I don't use Debian, so I do not know if the Debian OpenJFX includes the [standard Java client packaging tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html#CCHIHIIJ) (it should and probably does, but if it doesn't you could contact the package maintainers).  With those tools, on a Debian system, you can build a [self-contained application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI) which is deployable as a `.deb` (debian package).  Or you can just use the OracleJDK for your development and build a self-contained application based upon that.  With a self-contained application, users of your application do not need to have any kind of Java pre-installed on the system (as the required Java runtime is included in your application package).

*Related Question*

- [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)

Comment: Thanks I found the solution. To use JavaFX on  Openjdk  one needs Openjdk 8 and openjfx (in my case apt-get install openjfx and openjdk-...)