# JavaFX FXML API version warning

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have recently started noticing the following warning when starting my JavaFX application:

> WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.65 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.60

The FXML in question was created by Gluon Scene Builder 8.1.0, running with it's bundled Java, version 1.8.0_65. The application is launched with my OS Java, version 1.8.0_72.

The root node of the FXML does have the attribute

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65"
```

but I figured 1.8.0_72 > 1.8.0_65, so why am I getting this message? 
Is it something I should be worried about? And is there a way to ask the jre what is the JavaFX API version (which, apparently, is not the same as the Java version)?

Edit:
Running the code James_D suggested gives the following results:

> java version: 1.8.0_72-internal
>   javafx.version: 8.0.60

So, looks like the JavaFX version in the JDK is wrong? Or maybe I have an old jfxrt.jar? I'll look into that.

Comment: Try `System.out.println("java version: "+System.getProperty("java.version"));` and `System.out.println("javafx.version: " + System.getProperty("javafx.version"));`. They will almost certainly be the same, so maybe you are not running with the OS Java version you think you are.

Comment: They are in fact not the same. I have edited my question. I suspect since javafx still comes on a separate package on Debian it somehow was not updated.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're using open JDK (I guess), so JavaFX is a separate package. It looks like you have an old version of JavaFX. So I don't know of any FXML that is specific to u65 over u60, but in general I guess you should probably execute with a version at least as new as the version with which you built it. I'd just go ahead and bring your JavaFX version up to date with your Java version, if possible.

Comment: Currently the openjfx package is on version 8u60, so upgrading would mean building from source, which I am reluctant to do. There is some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19529820/4185959), but I am really confused as to why they are still two separate packages (and why the OpenJFX one has not been updated).

Answer (score 74):

If you use the form:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
```

The versioning is ignored. You'd only need it if you had some compatibility issue with another version.

Comment: I don't get the negetive voting for this answer - exactly this worked for me! The entry "xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" I do not have touched.

Comment: Mind you: SceneBuilder overwrites this!

Answer (score 15):

I have that problem also. I managed it just to change lines in *.fxml files:

javafx/8.0.171 -> javafx/8.0.141

Previously it was like this, it is a line in the begining of fxml file:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.application.word.view.LoginController">
```

Then I changed it for:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.application.word.view.LoginController">
```

And it works without any problem. But be carefull that it can be different if you use different jdk generations.

Answer (score 9):

I think your `JDK` version is `1.8.0_60` and `JRE` version is `1.8.0_65`.

So you should use the same version for both of them.

You can check your current `JDK` and `JRE` versions on your *command prompt* respectively,

```
java -version
javac -version
```

or you can go through the System properties using following *java code*,

```
System.out.println(System.getProperties());
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue.
Dunno what IDE you guys are running, but I fixed it on Eclipse.

Inside **project explorer** on right side of **JRE System Library** it was showing **[J2SE-1.5]**.
I right clicked **JRE System Library**, went in **Properties**.
Switched from **Execution Environement** to **Workspace default environement**.

If inside **workspace default environement** brackets it does not show your newest jdk version eg. **(jdk1.8.0_192)** your can change it by picking **Installed JREs** button and switching checked JRE.

If your jdk is not listed add it with **ADD** button and pick your JDK directory eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192, as home directory.

In case, for some reason, you don't want to change your default environement just pick **Alternate JRE** instead of **Workspace default JRE**. Then pick right SDK from dropdown menu.

PS. Yes you can change version under xmlns option inside your fxml file, but you will have to update entry every time you modify your fxml inside Scene Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Same was for me. as you mentioned your scene builder version is 8.1.0 while your Javafx version is 8.0.60. well they're different:)
two way to fix this

- uninstall current scene builder and install the one with same version of your Javafx
- every time you edit a FXML file using scene builder, change xmlns property in your header to your Javafx version

for example my javafx version is 9.0.1 while I use scene builder 10.0.1 but after editing in scene builder I change

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1"
```

to

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1"
```

for may own sake :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also having samme problem will i was loading my fxml file 
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.111
then i went to oracle website and update the jre till 171 update of java 8.0
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This warning occurs because your JavaFX API version and JavaFX runtime version are not the same.

- But if you try to manually change the version for the xml file, some of the buttons in the UI you created will not work.
- Therefore, you ignore the JavaFX API version of the FXML document.

**you change the xml file code line like below**

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Linux with Intellij IDEA.  I have solved it by installing the **latest Oracle JDK**, and providing its path in IDEA's "Project Sturucture" settings menu:

**File/Project Sturucture/Platform Settings/SDKs**

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues but I solved it by going through this steps

If you are using Intellij IDEA goto **File -> Project Structure -> SDKs** and click on the **(-) sign** to remove all other JDK you have before then click on the **(+) sign** to add the new JDK to the project from you **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172**.