# javafx warning with FXML

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

```
Oct 22, 2017 2:56:09 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.141
```

when I run my project, this warning occurs, and I input

```
System.out.println("java version: "+System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println("javafx.version: " + System.getProperty("javafx.version"));
```

output:

```
java version: 1.8.0_144
javafx.version: 8.0.141
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Presumably, you have created the FXML with Scene Builder running a newer version of Java. You can try manually changing the xmlns in the header, see this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210120/javafx-fxml-api-version-warning

Comment: Go [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) and download Scene Builder for Java 8.