# javaFX program not working after changing the scene builder and jdk

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, java-10

My program worked perfectly before, And I changed my scene builder to gluon scene builder 10 from JavaFx scene builder 2.0 to add some CSS styling. I added the styling and the program showed errors like  **WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 9.0.4**  And then I updated my JDK to version 10.0.2 but it stii shows errors like this.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/parser/CSSParser
    at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.<clinit>(GlyphIcon.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:560)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 27 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

My main class is

```
public class Main extends Application {    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../Interface/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("JFS");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();    
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

My Controller class is

```
public class Controller {

    public TextField newsletterEmail;
    public JFXButton regButton;
    public JFXTextField loginUserName;
    public JFXPasswordField loginPassword;
    public JFXButton loginButton;
    Connectivity connection = new Connectivity();
    Connection connec = connection.getConnection();
    SceneSwitcher sceneSwitcher = new SceneSwitcher();
    ViewMyAccount viewMyAccount = new ViewMyAccount();

    loginValidation validateLogin = new loginValidation();

    public void loginButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        System.out.println(loginUserName.getText());
        /*viewMyAccount.setMailLabel(loginUserName.getText());
        System.out.println(viewMyAccount.getMailLabel());*/


        boolean validateCustomer = validateLogin.CusLoginValidate(loginUserName.getText(),loginPassword.getText(),connec);
        boolean validateStaff = validateLogin.StaffLoginValidate(loginUserName.getText(),loginPassword.getText(),connec);
        boolean validateOwner = validateLogin.OwnerLoginValidate(loginUserName.getText(),loginPassword.getText(),connec);

        if(loginUserName.getText().equals("") || loginPassword.getText().equals("")){
            AlertBox.displayAlertBox("ERROR!","Both fields can't be empty!");
        }else{
            if(validateCustomer){
                sceneSwitcher.switchScene(loginButton,"customerView.fxml","Customer");
            }else if(validateStaff){
                sceneSwitcher.switchScene(loginButton,"staffView.fxml","Customer");
            }else if(validateOwner){
                sceneSwitcher.switchScene(loginButton,"ownerView.fxml","Customer");
            }else{
                AlertBox.displayAlertBox("ERROR!","Invalid Username or Password! ");
            }
        }     

    }

    public void registerButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        sceneSwitcher.switchScene(regButton,"register.fxml","Register");
    }

    NewsletterValidation validateEmail = new NewsletterValidation();

    public void newsletterButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws SQLException {


        boolean isNewsletterEmailEmpty = validateEmail.invalidError(newsletterEmail);
        boolean isValid = validateEmail.isValidEmailAddress(newsletterEmail);
        boolean isEmailExist = validateEmail.checkEmailExists(newsletterEmail.getText(),connec);

        if(isNewsletterEmailEmpty && isValid && isEmailExist){

            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO `nwemails` (`email`)\n" +
                    "VALUES (?);";        

            try {
                pstmt = connec.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstmt.setString(1,newsletterEmail.getText());

                int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("newsletter email update status = " + i);
                AlertBox.displayAlertBox("Alert!","You have successfully signed up for the news letter");


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }finally {
                pstmt.close();
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("Validation failed");
        }   

    }   

}
```

my FXML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@../CSS/dracula.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="227.0" layoutY="259.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Don't have an account?" />
      <Label layoutX="207.0" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="182.0" text="JFS" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="207.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="211.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Matura MT Script Capitals" size="53.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="241.0" layoutY="98.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="118.0" text="Jeff's Fishing Shack" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Marlett" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="186.0" layoutY="370.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newsletterButtonClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="210.0" text="Send me Updates" />
      <Label layoutX="111.0" layoutY="316.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="378.0" text="Or sign up for The free newsletter covering the top industry headlines" />
      <TextField fx:id="newsletterEmail" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="339.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="191.0" promptText="Email" />
      <JFXTextField fx:id="loginUserName" layoutX="203.0" layoutY="136.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="191.0" promptText="Username (email)" />
      <JFXPasswordField fx:id="loginPassword" layoutX="203.0" layoutY="185.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="191.0" promptText="Password" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="161.0" size="25.0" wrappingWidth="15.0" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="KEY" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="208.0" size="25.0" wrappingWidth="15.0" />
      <JFXButton fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="265.0" layoutY="225.0" onAction="#loginButtonClicked" text="LOGIN" />
      <JFXButton fx:id="regButton" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="284.0" onAction="#registerButtonClicked" text="REGISTER" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The stacktrace show this like as the wrong line

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../Interface/sample.fxml"));
```

I've been wasting more than 3 hours for finding an answer. So please help me with this.

the fontawesome version:

[image: font awesome versions]

Comment: Which FontAwesomeFX version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/Jerady/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser  @JoséPereda

Comment: I mean the version number, like 8.15?

Comment: There already were questions about the warning, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210120/javafx-fxml-api-version-warning . As for `CssParser`: The stacktrace indicates that you're unsing the version from the non-public api (`com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser`). I guess this class has finally been removed in java 10, since the class has been moved to the public api with the new name [`javafx.css.CssParser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/css/CssParser.html)

Comment: @JoséPereda I edited and added it to the question

Comment: I tried what they said in that question before Im posting this @fabian

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/parser/CSSParser
at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.<clinit>(GlyphIcon.java:48)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

indicates that one of your dependencies (`de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon`) is trying to access a non existing class (`com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser`) in your JDK 9/10.

With the Java 9 release, many JavaFX classes that were private (`com.sun.javafx.*`) were moved to public API (in this case, `javafx.css.parser.CSSParser`).

If you run on Java 9 or 10, you have to use third party dependencies at least compatible with Java 9.

From the list of your dependencies:

- ControlsFX

8.40.11 is compatible with Java/JavaFX 8. You need to use ControlsFX 9.0.0

You can download the [jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/controlsfx/controlsfx/9.0.0/controlsfx-9.0.0.jar) from Maven Central, or add the maven/gradle coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or:

```
compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:9.0.0'
```

- FontAwesomeFX

FontAwesomeFX 8.15 is also compatible with Java/JavaFX 8, so you need to use the 9 versions:

Jars:
 [fontawesomefx-commons](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/download_file?file_path=de%2Fjensd%2Ffontawesomefx-commons%2F9.1.2%2Ffontawesomefx-commons-9.1.2.jar), [fontawesomefx-controls](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/download_file?file_path=de%2Fjensd%2Ffontawesomefx-controls%2F9.1.2%2Ffontawesomefx-controls-9.1.2.jar)

or dependencies:

```
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-controls:9.1.2'
```

others:

```
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-emojione:3.1.1-9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-icons525:4.2.0-9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont:2.0.26-9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-octicons:4.3.0-9.1.2'
compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-weathericons:2.0.10-9.1.2'
```

Finally, as posted in comments, the warning is just an indication that your FXML was created with a newer version that the JDK running it. It can be ignored.

Comment: Pereda Thank you so much sir that worked perfectly. you are the best

Comment: Great. Now consider marking the answer as accepted. This will help in the future others looking for similar issues.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? I mean I don’t know how to mark it like that

Comment: Just click on the check mark to the left of the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You will be able to vote up or down as well when you have enough reputation.

Comment: Should the original fontawesomefx dependency be replaced by *all* those dependencies, or just commons and control?

Comment: @José Pereda: also, what does it mean when you write "compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-emojione:3.1.1-9.1.2' "? Is that Maven command line? Shouldn't these dependencies simply be added to the pom.xml file?