# scene builder does't import libraries specially fontawsome what to do?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm encountering a problem importing Scene Builder libraries.

I tried many times to import the `fontawsome` jar file into sceneBuilder. I also tried to manually import it, but none of that worked. No UI components will show in the list (look at the image), but when it does I get the "COPY FAILED" error. What should I do?

JAVA version : "1.8.0_171"
Scene Builder Version : 10.0.0
javafx.runtime.version=8.0.201

I tried to import the controls via jar file and also tried from repository

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly related to this question: [javaFX program not working after changing the scene builder and jdk
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670146/javafx-program-not-working-after-changing-the-scene-builder-and-jdk/51670666#51670666). Make sure you use the right dependencies for your Scene Builder version (i.e, SB 11 requires FontAwesomeFX 11)

Comment: this is isn't the same problem as mine i don't have the same exceptions as the question you proposed, and i checked the dependencies and again nothing seems to work

Comment: I didn't say "duplicated", but related. You need to edit your post and specify your versions (Java, JavaFX, Scene Builder), and how are you importing the control (via local jar or via repository)

Comment: I edited the post and added the versions

Comment: For Java 8, and JavaFX 8 libraries and controls you should stick to Scene Builder [8.5.0](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

Comment: it worked thank you