# Why does this JavaFX application look way different than when it's in SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, efxclipse

I was trying to make my first application on JavaFX but this frustrated me so much! These elements of the application are perfect in SceneBuilder, but now it's just misaligned!

[image: In SceneBuilder]

[image: In reality]

I think it's because of this error when I run the app:

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.231
```

I have tried to change the AnchorPane attributes to:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="129.0" prefWidth="205.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"">
   ...
</AnchorPane>
```

but it just fixes the warning and not the misalignment.

Here is my full code:

### Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
//import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Root.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### Root.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="129.0" prefWidth="205.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField layoutX="28.0" layoutY="23.0" />
      <Button layoutX="77.0" layoutY="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Two reasons: (1) You're using an `AnchorPane` which is not responsive to the window resizing; (2) You're setting the initial size of the `Scene`, in the code, instead of letting the `Scene` use the preferred dimensions of the root.

Comment: You’re putting a 129×205 AnchorPane in a 400×400 Scene.  What result were you expecting?

Comment: You can avoid the warning by not using such an outdated Java version. Switch to Java 11+. The current version is 13 and not 8.

Answer (score 1):

As @Slaw mentioned that [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) is not a responsive layout. You may consider using [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) with [CENTER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#CENTER) alignment as you have two nodes positioned with vertically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Pos?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox prefHeight="129.0"  alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="205.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="INPUT_FIELD" />
      <Button fx:id="SUBMIT" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Generally, `AnchorPane` can be set as a parent layout and you can put VBox on it and controls(Button, TextField, etc) can be added on the VBox.

> *I think it's because of this error when I run the app:*
>
> WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.231

No, it's just a warning! You can find a huge discussion over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210120/javafx-fxml-api-version-warning/38541473#38541473).