# JavaFX in Java 8 with non-oracle JDK

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

We're looking into transitioning to a community version of Java 8 (e.g AdoptOpenJDK).  I'm running into an issue with Java FX, which apparently isn't part of the community version.

I know one option is to move to a later version of Java and include it as a module. But, if we stick with Java 8, is the only option to use Oracle's JDK?

Comment: Have you looked into OpenJFX?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like it requires module support which only comes with Java 9+.

Comment: Im not sure exactly what AdpotOpenJDK does, but from their website it says it is built using OpenJDK, which does not include JavaFX in its code and requires you to install it separately via OpenJFX. You can install older versions of OpenJFX. You can read more about this [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX)

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243982/why-is-javafx-is-not-included-in-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-wily-15-10 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974003/javafx-comes-with-jdk-8

Comment: @HypnicJerk - Yes, that was the key. I found the Java 8 version and copied the overlays into the respective directories in the OpenJDK jre and it seems to be working. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JackBeNimble Would you please share your solution as an answer there?