# Compiling Java with VS Code, getting "restriction on required library" error message

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have seen this question asked and answered a few times for Java being compiled in Eclipse.  In my case, I don't have Eclipse.  I want to get my project compiled using VS Code.  I'm hoping there is a file I can create or edit to override this error message:

> Access restriction: The type 'Pair' is not API (restriction on
>   required library 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')Java(16777523)

Any help appreciated.

In my project the .settings\org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs contains

```
connection.project.dir=../..
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=ignore
```

PS My project uses gradle.

Comment: Another reason why Eclipse is rubbish.   Should still be part of your JDK 8 install, but not for newer JDKs.  You should reconsider JavaFX - not much support.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974003/javafx-comes-with-jdk-8

Comment: Could be but then I'm using VS Code, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

1.find `.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file in your project

2.change `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning`

to   `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference = ignore`

Comment: yeah, that's what I have.  I pasted the contents of that file into the op

Comment: No, in fact I got the error when that setting was already in place.

Comment: @user1443098 what's your project,gradle or maven ?

Comment: My project uses gradle for builds.

Comment: @user1443098 you should change `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference = ignore` in `.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` not in  `.settings\org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs`

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much!  Now, on to problem #2 (new thread)

Answer (score 0):

change file `./.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` with

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=ignore
```

run the command

```sh
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: Where would I find/run the mvn command