# Ubuntu won't run executable Jar files made with e(fx)clipse

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, jar, efxclipse

I made a simple "Hello World" program in e(fx)clipse, and created an executable Jar file. When I run it on Windows, it works fine, but when I try to do the same in Ubuntu - nothing happens.

I have OpenJDK-8 installed.

Also, when I type `java -jar helloWorld.jar` inside the Terminal, I get an error saying: `Could not find or load main class application.Main`

Again, in Windows everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk/19529820#19529820

Comment: @James_D Unfortunately this doesn't help.