# Using Java/JavaFX with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am working with Maven in Eclipse, in Windows. I made a JavaFX application that worked fine on other computers, including Linux Mint even without having JavaFX installed, I could not modified them but I could opened. Now I am trying to run it on Ubuntu. And I get this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Stage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I have a .pom that looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>moduloDistribuidor</groupId>
  <artifactId>myprogram</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>myProgram</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried to add JavaFX in the .pom just in case that was the problem, but  it still does not work.

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                     <mainClass>your.main.class.which.extends.javafx.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Javax and javafx are different. Are you trying to add javax, i.e. for web servlets, or javafx, for application development?

Comment: Sorry, Trying to add javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is what you need to add in your depencies to use java fx .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

the error you get is that plugin shouldn' be set at the root of your pom but must be :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>your.main.class.which.extends.javafx.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: no the jar should be in you jdk installation and that we describe in dependency when you right this     <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>

Comment: I get  "Missing artifact com.oracle:javafx:jar2.2"

Comment: did you have jdk installed ? is your java home location targeted jdk and nor jre?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_0171" . The other thing I dont know

Comment: The problem is something with this ubuntu, because in windows and linux mint I didnt even have javax in the pom and still worked

Comment: Ah! no the issue is about open jdk that not include javafx so i suggest you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk/19529820 then after javafx installed modifie you pom to target the javafx jar where it will be installed

Comment: Developing JavaFX-applications on OpenJDK always requires OpenJFX being installed. Normally installing that might already be sufficient, without the need to add system-scoped dependencies.