# How do I fix JavaFX runtime components are missing?

Tags: linux, javafx

I have the following installed on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS:

```
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, mixed mode)

javafx.runtime.version=8.0.161
javafx.runtime.build=b00
```

However I try to run the sample java application that uses javafx I get the following error:

```
$ java -jar Untitled.jar 
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I have tried to run it in Eclipse, Intelli, and in the terminal with the same error.

I have set the classpath

```
:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:.
```

I have copied all of the javafx files to the current directory.
I have tried everything I can find on the internet.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get install openjfx`? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk

Comment: Yes I have installed openjfx

Comment: Try this: `java --module-path /<path>/javafx-sdk-11/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls -jar Untitled.jar`

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 18.04 with `openjdk-11-jre` and `openjfx` installed you could use:

```sh
% java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH \
    -jar Untitled.jar
```

There is more information on [how to run JavaFX programs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction) at the [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io) site.

Comment: FYI: for the JavaFX it's enough only two modules `--add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.controls` instead of ALL-MODULE-PATH