# Where can I get pre-built JavaFX libraries for OpenJDK (Windows)

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing on Windows and replaced Oracle JDK with OpenJDK.

I've noticed that JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK.

Where can I get pre-built JavaFX libraries for OpenJDK (Windows)?

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Download seems to offer early access builds only.

Comment: A very quick google/checking oracles site would bring you to download site in OpenFX wiki...  https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Download

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be the worst of the lot, given that this was a change between Java versions, and those who don't update the quickest may be caught off-guard by this.  It probably shouldn't be reopened but I'm not thinking it's a particularly poor question.

Comment: JavaFX was only bundled with the Oracle-branded JDK/JRE. Oracle ceases that bundling in Java 11. You need to find a source for the necessary libraries [such as this](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Download) and then add to your build process. See InfoWorld article: [*JavaFX will be removed from the Java JDK*](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/java/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk/53205949  I answered there and I also tried that solution actually, so it definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaFX site [offers a link to download the JavaFX libraries](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Download) for Java 11 and newer.

Comment: how about java8 ?