# openjfx 1.8 does not contain javafx.fxml package

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I just installed openjdk 1.8 and openjfx on my system, also added jfxrt.jar to classpath. I can use now `javafx.scene`, `javafx.stage`, etc. But for some reason my jfxrt does not contain `javafx.fxml` package. May be I miss to add some library to my classpath or something else?
There is my classpath looks like at this moment:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar`
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar`
**`/usr/lib/jvm/openjfx/rt/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why - but openjfx package in Fedora 29 repository - doesn't contain fxml package... Solved by downloading openjfx-1.8 from Fedora 28 repo