# JavaFX not Recognized by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx, javafx-11

Even though I've installed ec(fx)lipse, Eclipse is unable to resolve any import statements with JavaFX.

I am running Eclipse version 2018-09 (4.9.0) on Ubuntu 18.04.

The Java I'm using is openjdk version "10.0.2". I have also installed OpenJFX.

How can I use JavaFX in Eclipse?

**A screenshot of my program:**
[image]

Comment: If you use openjdk package from Ubuntu repository, try [installing openjfx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35956637/2158271).

Comment: @haba713 I already have. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: This sounds like a classpath headache here.   I am wary of instlaling Java11 and screwing up my ability to use JavaFX.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Can you suggest anything?

Comment: I am flummoxed.  I am going to get a spare PC and experiment on it.  I don't want to gum up my production environment.

Comment: make sure the fx modules are added to the modulPath (right click project ->build path -> configure -> tab libraries -> select modulpath -> add external jars and then add the fx modules

Comment: .. and search the javafx-11 tag: there's a rather extensive answer to IDE config problem around fx11

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks! I couldn't figure out where openjfx put it's modules, so I downloaded them. They work though!

Comment: @kleopatra Erm, well I thought they did. Turns out Eclipse throws an error. ``Error: Could not find or load main class mainPackage.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application``