# How to use JavaFX in Java12 on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

When I am creating my JavaFX file in jdk12, it shows the following error:

> The JavaFX run time is not configured. Either use a JDK that has the JavaFX built in or add a  JavaFX library to classpath

How can I resolve this?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 1):

[JavaFX has been removed as of JDK11](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html) this means that `Orcale JDK11` and above does not contain JavaFX anymore. You have to get it yourself.

You can use Oracle `JDK version < 11` or an OpenJDK that has javafx build in or you can donwload it from here https://openjfx.io/ and get [started](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Here is a great SOF question about [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)

HTH

Comment: what about jdk12

Comment: With `=> 11` I meant version 11 and above - fixed the statement.