# JavaFX cannot find fonts on Gnome

Tags: java, javafx, archlinux, gnome

On a freshly installed Gnome, my JavaFX application cannot start via `mvn javafx:run` due to this error:

> Error: JavaFX detected no fonts: Please refer to release-notes for proper font configuration

However I don't find such a guide in the [release notes](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/jfx-12/doc-files/release-notes-12.md#release-notes-for-javafx-12).

How can I get JavaFX to work?

## Versions

jdk-openjdk 12.0.2.u10-10

GNOME Shell 3.32.2

Maven 3.6.1

fontconfig 2:2.13.1+12+g5f5ec56-1

### Maven Dependencies

maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0 with release set to 12

org.openjfx.{controls,web,fxml} 12.0.1

javafx-maven-plugin 0.0.3

Comment: Maybe this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk) question can help you.

Answer (score 6):

I've fixed by installing font 'ttf-dejavu'

```
sudo pacman -S ttf-dejavu
```