# JavaFX is missing in Java OpenJDK

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make an application that uses a JavaFX GUI. I've read in a Stack Overflow post that the packages are supposed to be integrated in the OpenJDK ([JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)). So I've set up my OpenJDK 13 ([jdk13 download page](https://jdk.java.net/13/)) and can't find the packages that I need to import. For example: I can't find the `javafx.application.Application` class.

Where is it located? Do I need to download something else?

### Edit:

It's strange that I have to prove that the link in the comments doesn't fit this problem, when the people who marked this question as a duplicate clearly didn't read that post at all. Furthermore I myself posted this very link in my question. The question provided in the link asks whether JavaFX support is still bad for OpenJDK and if there are Linux distributions that offer JavaFX in OpenJDK. The accepted answer in that question just compares the two versions of JavaFX in JDK and OpenJDK - an expected answer to the question.

I in my question  explain specifically what I expected, because I used JavaFX with normal JDK before. Since this is not the case with OpenJDK, I ask how to set it up properly. So please, if you mark something as duplicate to get your reputaiton - show me exactly where the answer is and don't post a lazy link.

I myself found the answer already and would post it, if this post gets unlocked ...

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529820/11212840
Here's described the issue you are interested in.

Comment: In those links you won't read that JavaFX packages "are supposed to be integrated in the OpenJDK".  Start here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Ok, the dupe was a mistake. However the question remains too broad. The openjfx site describes how to use it from (command line, IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans), in (modular, non-modular) mode, with (nothing, Gradle, Maven), on (Linux/Mac, Windows). I can assure you that the description works for me for the case of Eclipse+modular+nothing+Windows. And while I do not know how well the other 4*2*3*2-1=47 combinations work, I am pretty sure that you should describe which one you have tried and what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX is [not part of OpenJDK](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html) anymore. There exist some versions that integrate JavaFX  (i.e. [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-13/)). Or you can reference the OpenJFX builds at [Mavencentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx) in your build script.